# Trouble with array in card game

Tags: java

Basically this game asks for an integer between 1 and 52 and once the program has run it will output the card name and suit, it works for every integer apart from 52 which causes the program to crash. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i = 0;
    int[] cards = new int[54];

    boolean notZero = true;

    while (notZero == true) {

        System.out.println("Please input a number in the range 1-52: ");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int input = sc.nextInt();

        if (input == 0) {

            break;

        } else if ((input < 1) || (input > 52)) {

            System.out.println("Invalid input please try again.");
        } else {
            cards[i] = input;
        }
        i++;

    }
    outputCards(cards, i);
}

public static void outputCards(int[] cards, int arraySize) {

    String[] suit = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};
    String[] rank = {" ", "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10","Jack", "Queen", "King", 
                        "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King",
                        "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King",
                        "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

    for (int j = 0; j < arraySize; j++) {

        System.out.println(rank[cards[j]] + " of " + suit[(int) (cards[j] / 13)]);

    }

}
```

Comment: When `cards[j] == 52`, then `52 / 13 -> 4`, which is past the end of your suits array, making `suit[4]` your problem

Answer (score 0):

That's because array's index start from 0, so you might need to ask for input from 0 - 51. Another issue is print statement where you are using:

```
suit[(int) (cards[j] / 13)])
```

This means due to your input criteria, you are allowing 52 to be entered by user so this will evaluate to

```
suit[52/13];//suit[4]
```

While you have four elements in suit as well, but as i said above array index start from 0. So you can query array between 0-3. So this will lead to array index out of bound exception.

Comment: I have added an empty element at the start of the array to deal with that.

Comment: True but see that you have `int i = 0;` in your main method and you are setting user input from 0th element into array.

Answer (score 0):

the 1st card's INDEX = 0

the 52nd card's index = 51

so you have to do the inputted number -1

Comment: nope; he has an empty string element at index 0 of his lookup array.

Comment: you are right, the comment below the question is the right solution

Answer (score 0):

You should not increase the index `i++` when input is invalid; also, you should check in the while loop that no more than 52 values are typed by the user.

```
if (input == 0) {
    break;
} else if ((input < 1) || (input > 52)) {
    System.out.println("Invalid input please try again.");
} else {
    cards[i] = input;
    if (i++ > 51) break;
}
```

Additionally, in the case of suits, you can get an array index out of bounds, when i = 52, in the outputCards() method. That's because if the user inserts 52 values, 52 / 13 = 4, and `suit[4]` is out of bounds having only 0..3 items.